# troubles in generating XText plugins from ECORE

Tags: eclipse-emf, xtext, eclipse-emf-ecore

Iam trying to generate an XText grammar from a simple ECORE.
Im following this turorial http://koehnlein.blogspot.com/2010/03/xtext-for-your-ecore-models.html
However when I try to run the generated workflow I actually  get this error:

```
1    [main] INFO  lipse.emf.mwe.utils.StandaloneSetup  - Registering platform uri '/home  /andrea/workspace'
85   [main] ERROR mf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Launcher  - Problems instantiating module    org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Problems instantiating module org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
  at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:90)
at org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.launch.runtime.Mwe2Runner.run(Mwe2Runner.java:73)
...
..
```

any idea?

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is about "org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl" which is the language name of a default xText project.

What is the name of the ECore class defining your language?

I suppose it must be the same and at least exists.

Comment: same name and it does exist :)